# Zoom-in bug in iOS with primeng

Tags: ios, angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns, primeng-calendar

Hi I'm using primeng library with angular version 8.
I'm using 3 dropdowns and 1 calendar. And Only on iOS devices on mobile view When I choose an option from dropdown or click to choose a day on calendar, it zooms in.
I tested it with chrome, safari and firefox -> same issue on all the browsers

[link to video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/111iRprREndVKg4rMBH-lABgqKTEWwdNa/view?usp=sharing)

[image: image with issue]

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the font-size (built-in behavior of the browser for the pages with font-size less than 16px). You can add metatag to prevent this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```